# Transform DataFrame based on another DataFrame numbers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would transform a dataframe based on another dataframe transformed numbers.

Code

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random_integers(0,100,(100,2)), columns=['M','A'])
max_min = 100
step = 5
df1['RnkGroup'] = df1.groupby(pd.cut(df1['M'],
                 range(0,max_min,step)))['A'].transform('rank', ascending=False).round()
df1['RnkMeanGroup'] = df1.groupby(pd.cut(df1['M'],
                 range(0,max_min+step,step)))['RnkGroup'].transform('mean').round()
```

Is it possible transform a new `df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random_integers(0,100,(100,2)), columns=['M','A'])` based on the previous one?

I need something like `fit_transform` of `sklearn`.